# How to group events in timeline matrix in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have two sheets: **Events** and **Matrix**.

In the Events Spreadsheet below I have persons name, event start day, event end day and info.

**EVENTS**

[image: Events]

In Matrix Spreadsheet have one column as names and the rest of the columns are timeline with rolling dates.

**MATRIX**

[image: Matrix]

Now I need to get event info from list of events for the persons timeline and group them. For example Stallones all events should be shown in Matrix. Is there anyway to do this without VBA?

**Formula from matrix sheet:**

```
=IF(AND(B$1>=VLOOKUP($A2;Events!$A$1:$D$6;2;FALSE);B$1<=VLOOKUP($A2;Events!$A$1:$D$6;3;FALSE));VLOOKUP($A2;Events!$A$1:$D$6;4;FALSE);"")
```

Any suggestions to do this more neatly would be highly appreciated too. Thanks!

Comment: Are the `16.10.` and so on actual dates formatted to show that way or are they just numbers?

Comment: Yes actual dates formatted.

Comment: Okay what is wrong with the formula you are using?

Comment: I think it's incomplete, because it doesn't get the rest of the events. Just the first one from the table for Stallone.

Comment: Got it.  This can be done with formula, but it will be array type formulas and filling a large grid with array type formula will slow down the calculations and even possibly crash excel.  vba is the best answer.

Comment: I was afraid of that it could be get complicated. I haven't used vba much so I was looking for another solution, but I'll try to figure out the vba code for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this array type formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Events!$D:$D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Events!$A$2:$A$6)/((Events!$B$2:$B$6<=B$1)*(Events!$C$2:$C$6>=B$1)*(Events!$A$2:$A$6=$A2)),1)),"")
```

[image]

Realize that a page full of these will slow down the calcs.

---

My Events page:

[image]

Comment: This works! I'll have matrix that is about 300 rows and one year time span. Do you think it would be too heavy?

Comment: All you can do is try.  If it gets too sluggish then try your hand at vba.

Comment: I will. Thanks again Scott!

Comment: @msoi if this worked please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.